# Detect screen layout changes when additional screens are added

Tags: android, screen

Suppose a device has additional screens added through screen sharing, Zoom, WebEx, VNC etc. Can an application detect that there is more than one screen layout or if the screen layout has changed from the default display's dimensions?

If it is possible to detect additional screen layouts or when the dimensions change, how can I do it programmatically?